# Работа с Doc и Docx в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки, ms-word

В результате парсинга электронных писем возникла загвоздка, мой парсер

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import setuptools
import docx

name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла: ")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines = f.readlines ()  # читаем его построчно
t1 = lines [6]
t2 = lines [-5]
t3 = lines [-6]
for line in lines:
    if line.find ('Информирование') != -1:  # то что ищем
        t5 = line [0:40]  # определяет глубину
        print (t5)  # выводим на экран проверяем
        break
#--------
for line in lines:
    if line.find ('НА НР') != -1:  # то что ищем
        t4 = line [7:40]  # определяет глубину
        print (t4)  # выводим на экран проверяем
        break
name1: str = input ("Введите имя исходящего файла: ")
f = open (name1, "w+")
# f.write(str(t1 + "\n" +  t2))
f.write ('реквизит верхний// ' + str (t1))
f.write ('реквизит нижний// ' + str (t2))
f.write ('дата// ' + str (t3))
f.write ('\nнанр// ' + str (t4))
f.write ('\n// ' + str (t5))
f.close ()
```

позволяющий на данный момент вынимать из документов строки и определённые интересующие меня слова с определённой глубиной поиска, не позволяет делать всё то же самое но в файлах Word, как понятно из задачи работать приходится с различными форматами, RTF, DOCX, DOC.

**Подскажите как мне это исправить.**

Установка библиотеки не помогла
выполнял следующие действия

```
pip install python-docx
```

добавил в шапку

```
import docx
```

В результате выполнения появляется ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/АБИ/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/УрСО.py", line 9, in <module>
    lines = f.readlines ()  # читаем его построчно
  File "C:\Users\АБИ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 759: character maps to <undefined>
```

**Помогите разобраться в чём дело**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f = open (name, "r")` и `readlines` подходят только для работы с текстовыми файлами (которые можно например открыть и прочитать обычным блокнотом или другим простым текстовым редактором), но docx - это не текстовый файл, а по сути zip-архив с xml и другими файлами внутри.

Просто импорт модуля docx не добавляет никакой функциональности в функцию `open` и методы типа `readlines` - нельзя просто импортировать какой-то модуль, и думать что весь остальной код волшебным образом под это подстроится. Вам нужно искать примеры конкретно для `python-docx`, и переделать свой код на их основе.

С чего можно начать - пример последовательного чтения docx по абзацам и вывода на консоль (на основе кода из ответа [Read Docx files via python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32232121/4752653) by [@todd-vanyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2623625)):

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document('myfile.docx')

for docpara in doc.paragraphs:
    print(docpara.text)
```

Для работы с doc и rtf нужно использовать другие модули, т.к. эти форматы кардинально различаются, и код с использованием этих модулей возможно будет выглядеть совершенно по-другому, чем код для docx.

Comment: понято, спасибо