# Парсинг docx с помошью python

Tags: python, docx

У меня есть docs документ в нем есть текст/картинки/таблицы. И нужно распрасить его по абзацам и потом сформировать несколько новых документов. Подскажите с какой библиотекой проще всего это сделать. Хотелось бы в идеале проитерироваться по абзацем через for и в вектор накидать абзацы (мне не важно что находиться внутри абзаца). И потом из него сформировать новый docx.

Comment: Смотрите модуль python-docx, он позволяет в том числе циклом пройти по абзацам, см. пример тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1312036/1365 . Ну и создавать новые docx файлы тоже можно.

Comment: Видел эту библиотеку, но в ней немного проблемотично проитерироваться по абзацам, там больше идет итерация по по обьектам(картинки, таблицы, текст). И в контексте моей задачи и не очень подходит. Думал может есть какие-то библиотеки более подходящие мне.

Comment: Не понятно, чем в контексте вашей задачи вам не подходит итерация через `for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:`. Если нужен текст, берите атрибут text параграфа.

Comment: Как я понял параграф идет именно как текст. Он не включает в себя таблицы и картинки.

Comment: Вот тут есть примеры как более низкоуровнево обращаться к содержимому (к тем же таблицам): https://stackoverflow.com/q/29240707/4752653 . Скорее всего примерно так же можно и картинкам обращаться. P.S. собственно, код там оттуда взят: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40#issuecomment-60337012